# Eclipse Infinitest not running at all

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, infinitest

I've tried to get the [Infinitest Plugin](http://infinitest.github.io/) for Eclipse to automatically run my tests. According to the documentation, it hooks into all `@Test` annotated tests and runs the test class, as soon as the system under test class is changed.

The plugin was installed via the [eclipse update site](http://infinitest.github.io) provided at the github page. I do have the status bar as expected, but it simply stays yellow saying "No related tests found for last change".

So far I've tried several project types down to a simple java project - I can manually run all tests via `Run As -> JUnit Test` and JUnit works as expected. Infinitest is enabled in the preferences. Several tutorials, the (extremely short) documentation and pages have not helped. I don't have a filter file present.

I am running Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) on Ubuntu 15.10 with Infinitest 5.1.115 and JUnit 4.12.0.

Comment: @specializt I did not know that, thank you. I've un- and reinstalled Infinitest via the Marketplace - still the "no related tests found for last change", no matter if I change the system-under-test or the tests.

Comment: @specializt this is news to me too, what is the source of this information?

Comment: I think infinitest analyzes which files you have changed and only runs tests if they import the changed class or something like that.

Comment: Please disregard the above "never install anything manually via update sites", that is very much a recommended way to install plug-ins.

Comment: may I know what java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I installed **Infinitest Plugin** on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 (my current IDE) and I followed the instruction from [there](http://infinitest.github.io/doc/user_guide.html). I made a class with a method and I annotated with *@Test* (JUnit4 Library), then I made a text file named **infinitest.filters** that contain ".*"(regular expression). It is important that this text file to be on src folder (path: SomeProjectName/src).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even after adding the infinitest.filters as described, I have to change in behavior. No matter if I change the test-class or the tested class, Infinitest just shows "No related tests found for last change". I also use annotated test cases.

Comment: That's strange. I put the project [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/txd07n8djqjo9f0/Foo.zip?dl=0) on my dropbox if you want to check. Be sure that even if the project is on build automatically, clean it from Project->Clean... (In Eclipse IDE)

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have Java EE Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 with Infintest. Only when I put infinitest.filters file in the project folder my arquillian integration tests are skipped.

Folder project structure:

- src/

  - /main
  - /test
- pom.xml
- infintest.filters

infinitest.filters example ( skipping all tests from package ):

- com`\`.company`\`.app`\`.integrationtest`\`..*

Answer (score 0):

Infinitest doesn't work if the file path to the *.class and/or *.java file contains space character(s) - perhaps that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into the same problem, and resolved it by **activating**:

`Project -> Build Automatically`.